# compare 2 files, print lines of second file in the order of first file

Tags: awk

I have 2 files,

file1:

```
alfa     numbers numbers
vita     numbers numbers
gama   numbers numbers
delta    numbers numbers
epsilon numbers numbers
zita      numbers numbers
...
```

file2:

```
'zita'    keepnumbers keepnumbers keepnumbers
'gama' keepnumbers keepnumbers keepnumbers
'misc'  keepnumbers keepnumbers keepnumbers
'alfa'    keepnumbers keepnumbers keepnumbers
...
```

and I want to
print the lines of file2
of which the first word (in the first column)
matches with  the first word of file 1  (in the first column), BUT keep the order of first file.
The output should look like

```
'alfa'    keepnumbers keepnumbers keepnumbers
'gama' keepnumbers keepnumbers keepnumbers
'zita'    keepnumbers keepnumbers keepnumbers
```

I have already tried with

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]' file1 file2 > file3
```

but the order in file3 is like file2.
Moreover awk hits in the quote symbol ' is there a way to ignore it and read only the name inside quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are close, try

```
awk -v q="'" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{$1=q $1 q}$1 in a{print a[$1]}' file2 file1 > file3
```

- escaping single quotes is annoying, we could define a var `q`
- if you want to have file1 order, you could save file2 in array, then check it with file1
- save the array as `a[$1]=$0` so that we have the lines in file2, for later printing.

Comment: It works but I have a problem because the first word in some lines has a space in the end like 'alfa ' do you know a way to overcome it? Thank you very much!